# Swift 2 API Availability Check for storyboard

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9

I have an existing iOS application which is supports from iOS 8. i want to add new features only for iOS 9.

I have created a new storyboard for iOS 9 which is using the iOS 9 features like UIStackView. Appropriate storyboard file is instantiated based on the Device OS version.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard
    if #available(iOS 9, *, *) {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    } else {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainOld", bundle: nil)
    }
    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

But i am getting compilation error on Main.storyboard "UIStackView before iOS 9.0"

I am using Xcode 7 beta 5.

How to use the iOS 9 related features on the iOS 8 supported projects using Swift 2 #availability check

Comment: Maybe that will helps you: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6773

Comment: @Bannings, Developer forum comment suggest to change the deployment target to iOS 9. But I want my app should support from iOS 8, only for iOS 9, i want to add new feature. as swift provides language level support #available to validate the feature availability. i should be able to add the proper validation.

Comment: The error is from storyboard whatever you are use #available or not.

Comment: Yes. But I am instantiating the correct storyboard object based on the iOS version(using #available check). It looks like, i should use the new features only in the code not in the storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got an answer from Quincey Morris on the Apple Cocoa developer email list.

By Default 
 **Build for** setting in the File Inspector for storyboard file is "deployment Target", which is iOS 8, so compiler throws error.

If i change the "Build for" setting to iOS 9 on the storyboard which uses the iOS 9 features.  NO Error, Application runs in both iOS 8 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use such `#availability` feature in StoryBoard. If you would like to support iOS 8 with `UIStackView`, you should construct `UIStackView` from code, or use third party's compatible libraries. Like [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView) or [TZStackView](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView).

Comment: We can use iOS 9 feature in storyboard which is targeted for iOS 9 devices. Please look at my answer. As you suggested, if i want to implement StackView in iOS 8, then i can use the Open source which you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've created two storyboards, one for iOS 8 and another for iOS 9 and above.
For the iOS 9 storyboard go to the file inspector and set the minimum target to iOS 9, set the iOS8 one to iOS 8.

[image: Set to iOS9 in storyboard]

Then in code, whereever you create the initial view controller for that storyboard use:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    // create view controller from iOS 9 storyboard 
} else { 
    //create view controller from iOS 8 storyboard
}
```

Errors should go then. Obviously it's more code to manage but you get your native UIStack and when you drop iOS8 support you still have your fully functioning ios9 storyboard